# Exception Handler Code Snippet

Tags: c#, exception, code-snippets

I've been given a task to create a general exception handling code snippet, I have a couple of questions:

**Is it a good idea?** General exception handling leads to generalized messages as to what's breaking, making tracking hard.Leading to :

**What should I include in the snippet?** I figure less is more here but adding a log seems to be a good idea because I don't think the exception messages are going to be very specific.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't say it's a good idea, no. I tend to have relatively few exception handlers in my code. They're typically there to:

- Occasionally convert an exception of one type into another (although that's rarer in C# than in Java; whether it's a good thing or not is a different discussion)
- Catch errors at the root of the stack for a particular request / user action / whatever, usually just logging the result
- Handle bone-headed APIs which throw exceptions in non-exceptional situations

None of these takes long to write, and none of them comes up so often that it's worth having a common snippet.

Having a set of documented conventions around exception handling - with a discussion of the design in the same document - *is* a good idea though.

Comment: Could not agree more about the "documented conventions".

Answer (score 0):

it's better to add specific exception handling and including logs... But, you can add the general exception as well, to catch all unknown exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Stack traces (to those who can read them) are 90% of what you need.  Including the parameters passed into the erroring method will also GREATLY help in debugging.  If this is logging to a database, please be careful about logging sensitive pieces of data (PII or PHI).

If this is a web application, I would recommend saving a snapshot of the session as well, this can also help greatly in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) and AOP tools like PostSharp. They both provide great possibilities to debug and error-handle your code.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [these guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) as what should be handled by exceptions and what should not. Also, it's hard to [get exceptions right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/14/352949.aspx).
What I usually end up with is code that has few, if any specific exception handlers, and a global catch-all handler, that just logs the exception (including the stack trace).

That said, when you do use local exception handling, and if the default try.snippet is lacking, something like this might work (just the code included, the rest of the .snippet file is a bit obvious):

```
try 
{           
  $selected$
}
catch ($caughtExceptionType$Exception ex)
{
  $end$
  Logger.Error("$message", ex);
  //throw new $customExceptionType$Exception("$message", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a general exception handler strategy is only applicable at the entry points in the code that you'd like to treat *unhandled* exceptions. Maybe in a `Main` method for single-threaded application code or in the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Then, the strategy to use is highly *application specific*. Maybe you have a central log to add the information to, or a message queue that will trigger further processing (e.g., insert in a database and inform an administrator).